# Customize cell when registering a nib (Collection view)

Tags: ios, cell, uicollectionview, iboutlet, uicollectionviewcell

So with collection view, you MUST register a nib/class before trying to dequeue it:

```
// LOAD UP THE NIB FILE FOR THE CELL
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomNibCell" bundle:nil];

// REGISTER THE NIB FOR THE CELL WITH THE TABLE
[self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomNibCellId"];
```

However, if I have to do that, I don't know where to customize my "CustomNibCell." I don't want to customize the font/font size in "cellForItemAtIndexPath:" because it shouldn't be done every single time if I'm dequeueing a cell. And I can't do it in "- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder" because the IBOutlets have not been intialized yet.

Usually in TableViews you would just dequeue it and if it's nil, you would customize it only once. How do I do it, when I don't have the luxury of knowing when the heck the XIB is created?

Answer (score 1):

So I actually didn't know that dequeue created ALL cells visible to the view, I thought it just reused the same thing (one object) for everything x_x

[Why dequeue reusable cell twice in making custom table view cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806551/why-dequeue-reusable-cell-twice-in-making-custom-table-view-cell)

Then, I can also use `- (void)awakeFromNib` in which it has created the properties and you can modify them there.

Updated: